# IOREDIS: How to load balance read queries when there are multiple slaves to a single master

Tags: javascript, redis, load-balancing, redis-cluster, ioredis

I am using Ioredis client in JS for redis cluster. When I use scaleReads: "slave", read queries are sent to a slave node. But when there multiple slave nodes for a single key, then a random node is choosen.

How do I load balance the read requests to all the slaves for a master or is this concept of choosing a random node enough to distribute load?
Please suggest some ideas